# Restricting the user interaction with the remote dektop using VNC Server

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, guacamole

I am using [Guacamole](https://guacamole.incubator.apache.org/) Project for accessing remote desktop through a web browser. I have a simple client which connect to the remote desktop using VNC (RDP can also be used)

What I want is to limit the user interaction to a specific application or a portion of the screen. So that the user can not open other applications or make changes in the computer.

Is there any way I can limit the access using VNC or this feature can be implemented in any other way?

I am not looking for read-only option as the user need to interact with this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the VNC-server software.
i.e. Giving TightVNC-server the command line parameters like

```
-sharerect
-sharewindow
-shareapp
```

let you define areas, windows or full programms.

For further details on TightVNC see documentation: http://www.tightvnc.com/doc/win/TightVNC_2.7_for_Windows_Server_Command-Line_Options.pdf

Comment: As it is a custom made client. Can it cause the problem ? or it does not matter who is making the connection to the vnc server. i.e a Tight VNC viewer or a custom guacamole-client

Comment: A client will only see what a server serves ... as you say, I do not think the client is the culprit.

Comment: thank you. this is the feature I was looking for. but for me Its a bit confusing I am trying to use -shareapp and -sharewindow function. sharewindow seems to be not working correctly. for example I wrote -sharewindow Photos but it doesn't share the file explorer folder with the name Photos which I have opened on my desktop.